# Angular - An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'cssnano' Require stack:

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, npm-start

[An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'cssnano'
Require stack:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FziS.png)

I am trying to install in my localspace my old angular project.
I have  this installed specifications for my angular:

```
Angular CLI: 12.1.1
Node: 14.17.3
Package Manager: npm 7.10.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: undefined
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1201.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.1.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.1.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.1.1 (cli-only)
```

My old project package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@danieluac/scccf-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sistema de controle de conta corrente de fornecedores",
  "author": {
    "name": "Daniel AC",
    "url": "http://facebbok.com/danieluacDev",
    "github": "https://github.com/danieluac"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --buildOptimizer --commonChunk --vendorChunk --optimization --progress",
    "build:dev": "ng build --watch",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.1",
    "@coreui/angular": "^2.9.2",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
    "angular-google-charts": "^1.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.5",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^9.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^13.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^5.0.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.13",
    "npm": ">= 6"
  }
}
```

When i try to run

> **npm install or update**

I am getting this issue bellow:

```
C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend>npm start

> @danieluac/scccf-frontend@1.0.0 start
> ng serve

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'cssnano'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\optimize-css-webpack-plugin.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\common.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\index.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Anton\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\php p\SGDF-frontend\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-oLJa2O\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

What is the real problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to remove your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then run `npm install again?

Comment: After I deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`  it worked fine @GaëlJ